# directory class with 'address' style doesn't print all address fields

Tags: directory

My code below doesn't work because it doesn't print all address fields. By the way I've got a problem with french caracters therfor I'm using babel.

Could you please tell me what is wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

```
    % COMPILATION
% bibtex pour générer le fichier bbl, puis ensuite pdflatex pour générer le PDF
%
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@person{pge,
  name = "my name",
  birthyear = "my birthday",

  p.street = "my adress field",
  p.city = "my city field",
  p.zip "my city zip",
  p.state = "my state",
  p.country = "my country",
  p.phone = "## ## ## ## ##",
  p.cellular = "## ## ## ## ##",
  p.email = "myemail@free.fr",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french,longdates,break]{directory}


%\pagestyle{headings}
%  \renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
%   {\newpage\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

%\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
%  {\item\hspace{-\dirindent}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

  % CUSTOM: here is how I customize the directory for this user's guide:
\renewcommand{\dirsymbol}{\raisebox{1ex}{\tiny{[see \S\ref{sec:output}]}}}
\renewcommand{\Dirlabel}[1]{{#1}}
\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]{\item\hspace{-\dirindent}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

  \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \newcommand\MyURL{\begingroup\Url}
  \renewcommand{\Diremail}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\MyURL{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\Dirurl}[1]{\href{#1}{\MyURL{#1}}}
\fi

\def\baselinestretch{0.98}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\title{Annuaire de la famille}
\author{\dir{pge}}
\date{Version 1.00, 03 septembre 2015}
\maketitle

\nodir{*}

\directorystyle{address}
\directory{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `=` in

```
 p.zip ="my city zip",
```

With

```
@person{pge,
  name = "my name",
  birthyear = "my birthday",

  p.street = "my adress field",
  p.city = "my city field",
  p.zip = "my city zip",
  p.state = "my state",
  p.country = "my country",
  p.phone = "12345678",
  p.cellular = "12345678",
  p.email = "myemail@free.fr",
}
```

Address will be printed as desired. Also remember that you can't use `#` in TeX freely (I assume that you have used it only for this MWE).

```
    % COMPILATION
% bibtex pour générer le fichier bbl, puis ensuite pdflatex pour générer le PDF
%
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@person{pge,
  name = "my name",
  birthyear = "my birthday",
  p.street = "my adress field",
  p.city = "my city field",
  p.zip = "my city zip",
  p.state = "my state",
  p.country = "my country",
  p.phone = "12345678",
  p.cellular = "12345678",
  p.email = "myemail@free.fr",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french,longdates,break]{directory}


%\pagestyle{headings}
%  \renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
%   {\newpage\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

%\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
%  {\item\hspace{-\dirindent}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

  % CUSTOM: here is how I customize the directory for this user's guide:
\renewcommand{\dirsymbol}{\raisebox{1ex}{\tiny{[see \S\ref{sec:output}]}}}
\renewcommand{\Dirlabel}[1]{{#1}}
\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]{\item\hspace{-\dirindent}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

  \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \newcommand\MyURL{\begingroup\Url}
  \renewcommand{\Diremail}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\MyURL{#1}}}
  \renewcommand{\Dirurl}[1]{\href{#1}{\MyURL{#1}}}
\fi

\def\baselinestretch{0.98}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\title{Annuaire de la famille}
\author{\dir{pge}}
\date{Version 1.00, 03 septembre 2015}
\maketitle

\nodir{*}

\directorystyle{address}
\directory{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Run `pdflatex`, then `bibtex` and `pdflatex` and `pdflatex` on this file to get

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much !

I've got an other small problem with \directorystyle{**address-html**} style. Latex compilation print errors messages and doesn't build any .html output but only ..bbl with html content... This is erros messages when compiling with latex and **adresse-html** :

```
File `ANNUAIRE@PGE_Famille.bib' already exists on the system.
Directory citation `pge' on page 1 undefined on input line 57.
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&
Misplaced alignment tab character & <dd> <dt>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&
Overfull \hbox (187.00826pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (6.40639pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (82.70085pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (96.05931pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (55.51524pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
 There were undefined references.
```

By the way, I don't understand what you mean by "Address will be printed as desired. Also remember that you can't use # in TeX freely (I assume that you have used it only for this MWE)." ?